# create drop down in UITableView swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, drop-down-menu

I have gotten to the point where I have a selectable list of options, which are all loaded into the same .xib files.  I am trying to make it so upon the click on a cell a different .xib file is populated below, and all of the other cells shift down.  However, I am unsure of how to have 2 different xib's as TableViewCells in swift.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to insert a cell below the one that was tapped to show options?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways I can think of to accomplish what you are trying to do:

1. Single xib file: You should use a single xib file that hides the lower section that contains the options until the cell is tapped. When tapped, a property on the UITableCell class could be set, e.g. `isExpanded`. When `isExpanded` is set, your cell could unhide the options (by changing constraints).
2. Multiple xibs: When tapped, you could insert a new item into your datasource. In your cellForRow, you could check for some identifier and load either the regular cell or the options cell using something like this:

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if indexPath.row == optionsRow {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OptionsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! OptionsCell
       //Configure cell here
       return cell
   } else {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NormalCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NormalCell
       //Configure cell here
       return cell
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I was exploring the option of hiding part of the cell.  But I need my options cell to change based on swipes, while the top piece remained constant